# How to prevent user from interacting with web page via extension?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating an extension that is supposed to show an overlay and highlight the element the cursor is on. When the overlay is visible, the user should not be able to interact with the page (buttons, links etc should not work).

The code:

```
let overlay = document.createElement("div");
overlay.setAttribute("class", "as-overlay");

let panel = document.createElement("div");
panel.setAttribute("class", "as-root");
panel.setAttribute("id", "as-panel");
overlay.appendChild(panel);
document.body.appendChild(overlay);

____

.as-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index: 99999;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

I'm setting pointer-events to none in order to disable interactions. But it isn't working. Am I doing something wrong? (I've ensured the overlay takes full width and height, and it's z-index is high enough so that it renders on top of everything.)

Some help would be appreciated, I've been banging my head on this for quite a while, and a certain large language model was of no help ;-;

Edit: I've added in an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/em40qdc7/8/). Ideally, you'd expect clicking on the button or link to not do anything, since the overlay is there. But clicking on them works, I just can't seem to understand why.

Comment: `it isn't working` that's a pity, but not very helpful for debugging.  What does happen?  Is the overlay visible?  Does any of that code execute?  Can you see the overlay element appended to the dom in dev tools?  Ideally, you'll provide us with a runnable example of the problem.

Comment: Yes, the overlay shows up, but I can still interact with the elements on the page, even when the overlay is present. I've added in an example that shows the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of
> pointer events, the value none instructs the pointer event to go
> "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element
> instead.

All you need to do is remove `pointer-events: none` and that should fix your problem.  At least it fixes the example you provided.

Comment: Jesus Christ, I'm disappointed I spent so much time figuring out what's wrong when the solution was that easy. Thanks for the help, it's working :)

Answer (score -1):

For starters, these two have to be switched over because you can't have "panel" placed without the "overlay" being in place. Even if JS allows you to do this, it’s pretty illogical and hurts my brain!

```
overlay.appendChild(panel);
document.body.appendChild(overlay);
```

But anyway, if you have covered the entire page with a "shroud" then who cares about pointer events? :)

They’ll be clicking your shroud so if you haven’t added a click event on it... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm confused by your confusion. The OP is appending the `panel` to the `overlay`, then appending the `overlay` to the `body`. Pretty standard operation. It's standard to set up the DOM fragment the way you want it, then append the whole thing to the main DOM. But this answer doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: The shroud is meant to be transparent, it has a bg just to check if the overlay is showing up or not. The issue is that even though the overlay is present, and I'm clicking on a link/button below the overlay, the event for the link/button is being triggered, when it shouldn't, because of the pointer-events being set to none

Comment: It's like placing books on a bookshelf that hasn't arrived yet! :)